# Setting secure cookie for python client connection

Tags: authentication, webserver, tornado

I am currently attempting to set a secure cookie for a connection that is incoming from a Python client using Tornado, however, although setting the cookie *works fine for connecting incoming from browsers*, the set_secure_cookie call does not seem to work in the case of a Python client.

Below are excerpts from my Tornado server code which serves both WebSocket and HTTP Requests:

```
class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def get_current_user(self):
        return self.get_secure_cookie("user")


class LoginHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write('<html><body><form action="/login" method="post">'
                   'Name: <input type="text" name="name">'
                   '<input type="submit" value="Sign in">'
                   '</form></body></html>')

    def post(self):
        print("post received: ", self.get_argument("name"))
        try:
            print('trying to set cookie')
            self.set_secure_cookie("user", self.get_argument("name"))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        print("cookie: ", self.get_current_user())
        self.redirect("http://192.168.6.21/")

def main():
    application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/ws', EchoWebSocket),
    (r'/login', LoginHandler)
     ], cookie_secret="nescafeh")
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
    http_server.listen(9000)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

And attempting to send a POST request to get the cookie set on a separate client:

```
s=requests.Session()

r = s.post("http://127.0.0.1:9000/login", data={'name': 'hello'})
sleep(2)
print(r.text)
```

No errors are returned when trying to set the cookie, removing the 'self.redirect' line to see the response from the POST request does not help (there is no text printed).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`r.text` is empty because you're not writing anything to the response body in your handler.

Try `self.write("something")` in your handler's `post` method and `r.text` should print out the response.

You can also check `r.cookies` to see if your cookie is set or not.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to help my issue of the cookies not being set :/

Comment: @nescafeh What is the output of `r.status_code` and `r.cookies`?